# Swift and C APIs (CoreVideo)

Tags: c, swift, flags, core-video

I'm trying to use CoreVideo with Swift but I'm getting this error:

```
let flags : CVOptionFlags = 0
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, flags)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'CVReturn' to type 'CVPixelBuffer!'**

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'CVReturn' to type 'CVOptionFlags'**

Why does it matter that it can't convert the value if I'm not using it anyways? Should I be passing the 2nd argument differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it will be working.

```
var tmp : COpaquePointer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageBuffer).toOpaque()
var pixelBuf : CVPixelBuffer = (Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(tmp)).takeUnretainedValue()
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuf, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to compile! I'll have to look more into this pointer casting...

Comment: And also it'll be working because I'm using this code on my application

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with CoreVideo, but I guess the problem is more with `imageBuffer` init, as your first implementation seems correct.
This code works, at least compiles:

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
let optionFlags : CVOptionFlags = 0
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, optionFlags)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem seems to be that I can't seem to cast CVImageBuffer to CVPixelBuffer:

'CVImageBuffer' is not convertible to 'CVPixelBuffer'